# Can I observe a LiveData object that is based on a variable query?

Tags: sqlite, android-room, android-viewmodel

My code is experiencing a problem that I suspect may be self-inflicted. So I should probably answer this question first. Can I/how do I observe a LiveData object that is returned from a Dao that is based on a inner join query and a List parameter?

Unfortunately I do not yet have "10 reputation" on Stackoverflow, so apparently I cannot embed an image. But here is my ERD snapshot as it may help you see how my Entities are tying together: https://i.ibb.co/9YW0Vbx/Screenshot-at-2019-04-06-13-04-43.png

**PrayerListFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  mTagViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TagViewModel.class);
  mPrayerTagViewModel = 
  ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PrayerTagViewModel.class);
  ...
  //Update the tag list with the selected tags
  mTagViewModel.getSelectedTags().observe(this, new Observer<List<Tag>>() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Tag> tags) {   
        if(tags.size() > 0) {      
           mPrayerTagViewModel.setTagList(tags);
        }
     }
  });

  //Observe whatever prayers the view model has to show us
  mPrayerTagViewModel.getPrayers().observe(this, new Observer<List<Prayer>>() {
     @Override
     public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Prayer> prayers) {
        mPrayersAdapter.setPrayers(prayers);
     }
  });
  ...
}
```

**PrayerTagViewModel**

```
...
private List<String> mTagNames = new ArrayList<>();
...
public LiveData<List<Prayer>> getPrayers() { return getPrayersForTags(mTagNames); }
...
public void setTagList(List<Tag> tags) {
   mTagNames = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Tag tag: tags) {
      mTagNames.add(tag.getName());
   }
}
```

**ITagDAO**
This returns LiveData objects that I have no trouble observing:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tag_table ORDER BY name")
LiveData<List<Tag>> getAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM tag_table WHERE selected ORDER BY name")
LiveData<List<Tag>> getSelected();
```

**IPrayerTagDAO**
But I am running into issues observing this, so I want to first make sure it is valid syntax:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM prayer_table " +
       "INNER JOIN prayertag_table " +
       "ON summary=fk_summary " +
       "WHERE fk_name IN (:names)")
LiveData<List<Prayer>> getPrayersForTags(final List<String> names);
```

If it is valid syntax, am I possibly losing my observable in my fragment because the call to getPrayers() in PrayerTagViewModel returns a new ViewModel, i.e. a different ViewModel than the one I have started observing in the fragment??

Answer (score 1):

Persistence paid off! I had a sneaky suspicion the mysterious Transformations.switchMap could resolve my issue, but only after a lot more reading did I realize how.

**PrayerTagViewModel** (modified)

```
...
private PrayerTagRepository mPrayerTagRepository;
private MutableLiveData<List<String>> mTags = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LiveData<List<Prayer>> mPrayers =
   Transformations.switchMap(mTags, mTags -> getPrayersForTags(mTags));

public PrayerTagViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
   super(application);
   mPrayerTagRepository = PrayerTagRepository.getRepository(application);
}
...
public LiveData<List<Prayer>> getPrayersForTags(final List<String> names) {
   return mPrayerTagRepository.getPrayersForTags(names);
}
public LiveData<List<Prayer>> getPrayers() { return mPrayers; }
...
public void setTagList(List<Tag> tags) {
   List<String> tagNames = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Tag tag: tags)
      tagNames.add(tag.getName());
   mTags.setValue(tagNames);
}
```

**PrayersListFragment** (modified)

```
...
//Update the tag list with the selected tags
mTagViewModel.getSelectedTags().observe(this, new Observer<List<Tag>>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Tag> tags) {
      Log.i(this.getClass().getName(),"onChanged :: Tag size = " + tags.size());
      if(tags.size() > 0)
         mPrayerTagViewModel.setTagList(tags);
   }
});

//Observe whatever prayers the view model has to show us
mPrayerTagViewModel.getPrayers().observe(this,
   prayers -> mPrayersAdapter.setPrayers(prayers));
```

**Solution:** The switchMap lets my Fragment observe a dynamically changing LiveData (actually a MutableLiveData) from my ViewModel.